# I have a problem with testing custom implementation of UITextField(cannot use ClearText(query))

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I have created a custom DecimalTextField from UITextField and I have a problem to auto test it:

```
    [Register(nameof(DecimalTextField)), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public class DecimalTextField : UITextField
    {
        private NSNumberFormatter _numberFormatter;

        protected internal DecimalTextField(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) => SetUp();

        public DecimalTextField(NSCoder coder) : base(coder) => SetUp();
        public DecimalTextField(CGRect frame) : base(frame) => SetUp();

        public int MaxLength { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;
        public int MaxDecimalPlaces { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;

        public string RegexPattern
            => string.Format(
                FormattingConstants.DecimalNumberRegexWithPrecision,
                _numberFormatter.DecimalSeparator,
                MaxDecimalPlaces);

        private void SetUp()
        {
            KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;
            _numberFormatter = new NSNumberFormatter();
            _numberFormatter.Locale = NSLocale.CurrentLocale;

            ShouldChangeCharacters = (textField, range, replacementString) =>
                ContainsOnlyOneSeparator(textField, range, replacementString)
                && CheckIsLengthWithinLimits(textField, range, replacementString);
        }

        private bool ContainsOnlyOneSeparator(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
        {
            string newString = textField.Text.Insert((int)range.Location, replacementString);
            var regexTester = new Regex(RegexPattern);
            return regexTester.IsMatch(newString);
        }

        private bool CheckIsLengthWithinLimits(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
        {
            int currentCharacterCount = textField.Text?.Length ?? 0;
            if (range.Length + range.Location > currentCharacterCount)
                return false;

            int newLength = currentCharacterCount + replacementString.Length - (int) range.Length;
            return newLength <= MaxLength;
        }
    }
```

I am binding this field with:

```
set.Bind(QuantityDecimalTextFiled).For(v => v.Text).To(vm => vm.Quantity).WithConversion<DecimalTextFieldSafeDecimalConverter>();
```

where converter is:

```
public class DecimalTextFieldSafeDecimalConverter : MvxValueConverter<decimal?, string>
    {            
        private  NSNumberFormatter _numberFormatter = new NSNumberFormatter();

        public DecimalTextFieldSafeDecimalConverter()
        {
            _numberFormatter.Locale = NSLocale.CurrentLocale;
        }

        protected override string Convert(decimal? value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!value.HasValue)
                return string.Empty;

            string valueAsString = value.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return valueAsString.Replace(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator, _numberFormatter.DecimalSeparator);
        }

        protected override decimal? ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == _numberFormatter.DecimalSeparator)
                return null;

            var number = _numberFormatter.NumberFromString(value);
            return (decimal) number.NSDecimalValue;
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to use `IApp.ClearText(c => c.Id("xxxxEntry").Index(0))` ("xxxxEntry" is the automation id for my DecimalTextField) I am receiving this exception:

```
System.Exception : Error while performing ClearText(Id("xxxxEntry").Index(0))
  ----> System.Exception : Error while performing ClearText()
  ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection refused
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused
```

Please keep in mind that this exception you can get only if DecimalTextField already have some text.

Do you know is it possible to fix in my code or I should raise a bug for Xamarin.UITest framework?

Comment: Hi , do you refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/get-started-xamarin-forms) document to get started with UITest and Xamarin.Forms ?

Comment: You should just need to do `ClearText(c => c.Id("xxxxEntry"))`, why are you adding `.Index()`?

Comment: @Saamer It doesn't work in both situations

Comment: It seems like the clear text doesnt work because of a `HttpRequestException `/`Connection refused` issue. 1) Have you provided internet permissions? 2) Are you seeing this error on iOS & Android? 3) Are you seeing this error on device and simulator/emulator?

Comment: @Saamer 
1. I have provided internet permission.
2. Error occurs only on iOS
3. It is reproducible on device and simulator